# ¿Cómo convertir java.util.UUID en SQL Server varchar?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, mybatis, uuid

Estoy trabajando con mybatis, flyway migrations y SQL Server como motor de base de datos. Tengo una tabla en la base de datos con un campo de tipo varchar para almacenar un uuid de un item. El problema surge cuando deseo obtener dicho valor desde la base de datos y trabajarlo como un Java.util.UUID. Al hacerlo viene como null, y no salta ningún error. Intenté usar el siguiente UUIDTypeHandler, pero no afectó en nada. Este es el código:

```
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedTypes;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandler;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.UUID;

@MappedTypes({UUID.class})
public class UuidTypeHandler implements TypeHandler<UUID> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UuidTypeHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, UUID parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        if (parameter == null) {
            ps.setObject(i, null, Types.OTHER);
        } else {
            ps.setObject(i, parameter.toString(), Types.OTHER);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public UUID getResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return toUUID(rs.getString(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public UUID getResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        return toUUID(rs.getString(columnIndex));
    }

    @Override
    public UUID getResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        return toUUID(cs.getString(columnIndex));
    }

    private static UUID toUUID(String val) throws SQLException {
        if ("".equals(val) || val == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return UUID.fromString(val);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            LOG.warn("Bad UUID found: {}", val);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Cómo se podría solucionar??

Comment: por que lo manejas como string en sql, manejalo como uniqueidentifier en sql y no deberias tener problemas